# PHP / Using a class to download a .vcf file

Tags: php, forms, submit

today I need help for this form. It will save data in a vcard, in .vcf format and this form is in a html page and i can't submit to another page. So now, if I click the save button, it download properly in .vcf extension but in the file there is the entire html page... I need to download only the vcard, and im using a class retrived from here https://github.com/facine/vCard/blob/master/vCard.class.php. 
Maybe with simple_html_dom.php I can extract the div that i need...
Thanks for help!

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<button name="btn_func" class="btn waves-effect waves-light red">
 <span class="white-text">Salva nella rubrica</i></span>
</button>
<div id="savecard">
<?php 
 include('simple_html_dom.php');                        
 include('vcard.php');
 $card = new vCard();
 $card->setnew("first_name", $params['user']->first_name);
 $card->setnew("last_name", $params['user']->last_name);
 $card->setnew("birthdate", $params['user']->birthdate);
 $card->setnew("home_address", $params['user']->address);
 if(isset($_POST['btn_func'])){
 $card->download();
 }
 ?>
 </div></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just Add header to your PHP Code.**

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<button name="btn_func" class="btn waves-effect waves-light red">
 <span class="white-text">Salva nella rubrica</i></span>
</button>
<div id="savecard">
<?php 
 include('simple_html_dom.php');                        
 include('vcard.php');
 $card = new vCard();
 $card->setnew("first_name", $params['user']->first_name);
 $card->setnew("last_name", $params['user']->last_name);
 $card->setnew("birthdate", $params['user']->birthdate);
 $card->setnew("home_address", $params['user']->address);
 if(isset($_POST['btn_func'])){
header('Content-Type: text/x-vcard');
 $card->download();
 }
 ?>
 </div></form>
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: So from where you are retrieving the user details from database?

Comment: From variables, but this is not a problem. Inside the .vcf file there is all the html code and the correct code of the vcard, I need only this without all the html code.